# A proof for $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(x^2 + y^2)}{x^2 + y^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

To prove the following limit $ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{\sin(x^2 + y^2)}{x^2 + y^2}  = 1$ is it sufficient to say that around $(x,y) \to (0,0) $ we have  $\sin(x^2 + y^2) \approx x^2 + y^2$?

Comment: Write $x^2+y^2 = r^2$. Now what happens to $r$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$? What does this tell you about your limit?

Answer (score 2):

$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{\sin(x^2 + y^2)}{x^2 + y^2}  = 1
\iff \left[\forall r>0\ \ \ \exists \delta > 0\ \ \ 
d((x,y),(0,0))<\delta\implies
\left| \dfrac{\sin(x^2 + y^2)}{x^2 + y^2} - 1\right|\le r\right]\\
\iff \left[\forall r>0\ \ \exists \delta > 0\ \ \ 
x^2+y^2<\delta^2\implies
\left| \dfrac{\sin(x^2 + y^2)}{x^2 + y^2} - 1\right|\le r\right]\\
\iff \left[ \forall r>0\ \ \exists \delta > 0\ \ \ 
0\le U<\delta^2\implies
\left| \dfrac{\sin(U)}{U} - 1\right|\le r\right]\\
\iff \lim_{U \to 0^+} \dfrac{\sin(U)}{U}  = 1
$$which is true because $\sin'(0) = \cos(0) = 1$.

But *both* $x$ and $y$ must be close to zero.

Comment: This is a Calc 3 problem, so the OP may not be familiar with vector space norms.  It's probably better to write $d((x,y),(0,0))$ or something.

Comment: ok for that. anywaym what is calc3?

Comment: That looks way uglier than actually is.

Comment: this is just a definition.

Comment: The definition is important and *can* be useful to clarify things, but in this particular instance I feel that it just adds to the confusion. If you have enough mathematical sophistication to follow the proof above without batting an eye then you (probably) wouldn't be asking the question in the first place, given the way undergraduate courses are structured :)

Answer (score 1):

Since $(x, y) \rightarrow (0,0)$ consider $r^2=x^2+y^2 $ then we can consider the limit of $\frac {\sin (r^2)}{r^2}$, so we will consider what happens when $r\to 0$

$\lim _ {r\to 0}\frac {\sin (r^ 2 )}{r^2}=\frac {0}{0}$,

Now we apply l'hospitals rule, differentiating the top and bottom to get:

$\lim _ {r\to 0}\frac {\sin (r^ 2 )}{r^2}=\lim _ {r\to 0}\frac {2r\cos(r^ 2 )}{2r}=\lim _ {r\to 0}\cos(r^ 2 )=1 $.

Comment: there are functions for which $f(x,x)\to 0$ but $f(x,y)\nrightarrow 0$ (consider $f(x,y) = 1_{x-y\neq 0}$ for an example).

Comment: For your example if you let x and y go to 0 you would get zero

Comment: yes, I made an edit.

Comment: What's the 1 thing?

Comment: $1_A(x)=1$ when $x\in A$ and 0 otherwise. anyway, the way you handle the situation is incorrect.

Comment: Would it be better to do a change of variables $x^2+y^2=r^2$, take $r\to 0$, then L'hopital it to get $1$?

Comment: Yes it would. See my answer.

Comment: Okay, redone with l'hopitals rule etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's not even true that $\sin(x^2 + y^2) \approx x^2 + y^2$ if $x$ is close to $0$, because $y$ could be quite large.  What is true is that if $x^2+y^2$ is small, then $\sin(x^2 + y^2) \approx x^2 + y^2$.  But in any case, even if you said that it wouldn't be a very rigorous limit proof, because you're just talking about approximations.  But it could be the start of the proof if you take the Taylor series of $sin(x^2+y^2)$ and take the limit.  Or, more simply, you can take @Dane's suggestion and do $r^2 = x^2+y^2$.

Comment: I am very sorry , I mean't around (0,0) , not x = 0