# Is the function $f(x,y)=\frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2 + y^2}$ continuous?

Tags: analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

choose the correct answer:

> i) Let
>   $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$
>
> $
> f( \, (x,y) \, ) = 
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2 + y^2}, & \text{if $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$,}  \\[6pt]
> 1,                       & \text{if $(x,y) = (0,0)$.}
> \end{cases}
> $
>
> The function $f$ is continuous on:
>
> (a) $\mathbb{R}^2$
>
> (b)$\mathbb{R}^2 - \{(0,0)\}$
>
> (c) $\{(0,0)\}$
>
> (d) $ \phi$

My answer is:

(a) $\mathbb{R}^2$, because

$f^{-1} (\{1\})=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb {R}^2 : (x,y)=(0,0) \}$

$\{1\}$ is closed in $\mathbb {R}$ and $f^{-1} (\{1\})$ is closed in  $\mathbb {R}^2$

> ii) Let
>   $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$
>
> $
> f( \, (x,y) \, ) = 
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2 + y^2}, & \text{if $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$,}  \\[6pt]
> 0,                       & \text{if $(x,y) = (0,0)$.}
> \end{cases}
> $
>
> The function $f$ is continuous on:
>
> (a) $\mathbb{R}^2$
>
> (b)$\mathbb{R}^2 - \{(0,0)\}$
>
> (c) $\{(0,0)\}$
>
> (d) $ \phi$

My answer is:

(b)$\mathbb{R}^2 - {(0,0)}$, because the function $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$

$ $$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2 + y^2}= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\sin t}{t}= 1 \neq f(0,0)=0
$

true ?

Comment: Have you tried converting to polar coordinates?

Comment: Some related posts: [A proof for $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(x^2 + y^2)}{x^2 + y^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/734568) and [How to specify the limit of a piecewise function when a point for continuity is given?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1892420) Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7B%5Csin(x%5E2%2By%5E2)%7D%7Bx%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%7D%24&p=1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i) Since the functions $f_1(x,y)=\sin(x^2+y^2)$ and $f_2(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ are continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ with $f_2(x,y)\neq 0$ on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$, then $f|_{\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}} = f_1/f_2$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$. Thus, for $f(x,y)$ to be continuous, it suffices to verify that $f(x,y)$ is continuous in $(0,0)$. Note that $(0,0)$ is an accumulation point of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $(x,y)\to(0,0) \Leftrightarrow r=x^2+y^2\to 0$, and then follows
$$
\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y) = \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2} = \lim_{r\to 0} \frac{\sin(r)}{r}= 1 = f(0,0),
$$
therefore $f$ is continuous in $(0,0)$.
ii) Similarly to the previous question, $f$ can only be continuous in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$.